# What is the forum to discuss topics related to internet traffic engineering?

Tags: discussion

I am unable to find a correct forum to post my questions. This must be a dilemma for people treading in boundaries. I have a few questions related to traffic engineering. Where should I post? Here, I find the gatekeepers quite harsh, in a well meaning way .. But still I have questions :-(

Comment: Do you mean traffic engineering on the public Internet?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: That is up to the Internet carriers, and you have no control over their networks. Each carrier has its own policies. Question about networks over which you have no control are off-topic on NE.